# Adjusting standard errors in two-step maximum likelihood estimation

Tags: variance, maximum-likelihood, estimation

Suppose we want to solve

$$max_{\theta} \sum_{i}^N log f(y_i|x_i; \theta, \gamma).$$

Here, $\theta$ and $\gamma$ are two parameter vectors. The problem above derives an estimate of $\theta$, taking the parameter vector of $\gamma$ as given. Suppose we know that $\gamma\sim N(\mu, \Sigma)$. Then, we can plug in $\mu$ as a consistent estimate of $\gamma$ in the problem above and derive a consistent estimate of $\theta$.

In this case, I believe that we should correct the standard errors for $\theta$ for the fact that $\gamma$ are random variables. However, I am not entirely sure how to correctly adjust the standard errors. Wooldridge, in "Econometric Analysis of Cross Section and Panel Data", writes that if the first-stage estimator of $\gamma$ is of the form

$$ \sqrt{N}(\hat{\gamma} - \gamma) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} \Sigma_{i} r_i(\gamma) + o_p(1), $$

then

$$\hat{Avar}(\hat{\theta}) = (\Sigma_i \hat{H}_j)^{-1}(\Sigma_i \hat{g}_i \hat{g}_i')(\Sigma_i \hat{H}_i)^{-1},$$

where

$$\hat{g}_i = \hat{s}_i + \hat{F}\hat{r}_i,$$

$s_i = \frac{\partial log f_i}{\partial\theta}$ is the score of the likelihood and $F$ is the gradient of the score with respect to $\gamma$. Now I am wondering what an estimator for $r_i$ would possibly be in this case. In particular, one would need to calculate $r_i r_i'$, which could be equal to the covariance of $\gamma$ ($\Sigma$), but I am not entirely sure.